# How query return multiple values in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Please I have this error

> "org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique
>   result: 2"

It works perfectly when I have one result and I need to show the two(or more) results found but I don't know how!

Here is my code:

```
 public class ContactImplDataBase implements ContactDAO {
    //.......
    ...
    public Contact getContactByType(String type) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Contact.class)
         .add(Restrictions.like("type", type));
     tx.commit();  
     return (Contact)criteria.uniqueResult();}
    }
```

And:

```
 public class ContactImpl implements ContactDAO {
    //...
    ..
    @Override
    public Contact getContactByType(String type) {
        Contact contact=null;
        for(Contact c:contacts){
            if(c.getType().equals(type)){
            contact=c;
            break;
            }
        }
        return contact;
      }
    ...}
```

And in the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/rechercheContact")
    public String rechercheContact(Model model, @RequestParam(value="type")         String type){
        List<Contact> liste=new ArrayList<Contact>();
        liste.add(services.getContactByType(type));

        model.addAttribute("listeContact", liste);
        model.addAttribute("type", type);

        return "ex";
     }
```

Any help ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a little code review here:

- Format your code for readability.
- `getContactByType` is wrong because there could be more than one contact for one type, so rename your method to `getContactsByType`
  and let it return a `List<Contact>` instead of a single `Contact`.
  This has to be changed also in the non provided interface `ContactDAO`.
- The class `ContactImpl` does not make any sense to me.
- Don't use transactions for database reads.

Finally you should get it to work:

```
public class ContactImplDataBase implements ContactDAO {

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getContactsByType(String type) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Contact.class)
            .add(Restrictions.like("type", type));  
        return (List<Contact>)criteria.list();
    }
}
```

Your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchContacts")
public String searchContacts(Model model, @RequestParam(value="type") String type) {
    List<Contact> list = services.getContactsByType(type);

    model.addAttribute("contactList", list);
    model.addAttribute("type", type);

    return "ex";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function here:

```
public Contact getContactByType(String type) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Contact.class)
         .add(Restrictions.like("type", type));
     tx.commit();  
     return (Contact)criteria.uniqueResult();} // TAKE NOTE OF THIS
    }
```

You have set it to only return single unique result.

So that means if there is no single unique result it will thrown an exception.

You have two options here:

1. Ensure data you searching for is via a unique identifier
2. Change your getContactByType function to return a List rather than Contact and change (Contact) criteria.unique() to criteria.list();

Answer (score 0):

Error message appears to be a hibernate query data return error, presumably the trigger:

```
return (Contact)criteria.uniqueResult();}
```

Show that your contact table uses the "type" field query to return multiple records, so there are two ways to solve the solution:

1. criteria.uniqueResult() => if (Criteria.list() > 0) return criteria.list().get(0)
2. Modify the number of your database records, maintain

> select count(*) contact where type='xxx'

returned 1 records, more than other data deleted. Can also be used to index the database.